# How to hide .NET Core compatibility warnings when referencing .NET 4.6 NuGet package in VS 2017.3

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2017, compatibility, .net-core-2.0

I'm working on a .NET Core CLI app that needs to reference a 3rd party NuGet package that has not been published with a `netcoreappX.X` target. I've run the *Analyze Project Portability* tool on it and got **100%** compatibility, which is expected, as this is a relatively simple library.

The problem then comes in the form of this annoying NuGet warning:

> **Warning:    NU1701**
>       Package 'XXXXXX 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Is there a way to hide this warning for a specific NuGet package?

Comment: For Visual Studio Code check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002945/disabling-a-specific-compiler-warning-in-vs-code).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found an answer to my question in a Google Images search, which led me to this seemingly unrelated SO post:

> [Suppressing issues from Roslyn code Analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720443/suppressing-issues-from-roslyn-code-analyzers)

In short, the Properties page of the NuGet package reference has a **NoWarn** attribute where the error code can be specified, as shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Also work with VS 2022.
[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 1):

As of VS2019 (v 16.9.1) you can add the code (or codes, comma separated) to the property `Suppress Warnings`, then rebuild the solution.

[image: NuGet Package Properties]

Comment: Using the Suppress Warning on a root NuGet package works, but a dependency package can also cause a warning that is not suppressed.  Example in a .NET 6 class library using NuGet package:  iTextSharp, which depends on BouncyCastle.  The warning for iTextSharp goes away, but the BouncyCastle warning stays.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your project (.proj) file and suppress the warning codes at the project level.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <NoWarn>NU1701;RAZORSDK1006</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```