# Disable IDE0002 rule in some cases?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, visual-studio-2022

Can you somehow fine-tune the rule "Simplify member access (IDE0002)" in Visual Studio 2022? It's mostly useful, until it's not :)

```
internal class Good_God_Please_Help_Why_Is_This_Class_Name_So_Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong {

    internal class SomeConstants {
        public const string A = "A";
        public const string B = "B";
    }
}

internal class Salvation : Good_God_Please_Help_Why_Is_This_Class_Name_So_Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong { }

internal class Test {
    void SomeMethod() {
        var a = Salvation.SomeConstants.A;
    }
}
```

Code above produces following simplification:

[image: IDE0002 gone wild]

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the bullet saying, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable "Name can be simplified" IDE0003 fix hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857982/disable-name-can-be-simplified-ide0003-fix-hint)

Comment: See also [Suppressing issues from Roslyn code Analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720443/suppressing-issues-from-roslyn-code-analyzers)

Comment: I don't think so, because I don't want to disable this rule, just make it not "fire" in some cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use `SuppressMessage`:**

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

internal class Test
{
    [SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE0002")]
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        var a = Salvation.SomeConstants.A;
    }
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**Alternatively, import static member:**

```
using static Good_God_Please_Help_Why_Is_This_Class_Name_So_Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong;

internal class Test
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        var a = SomeConstants.A;
    }
}
```

Comment: SuppressMessage seems to work for a whole class, too. That's good enough for me, thanks!

Comment: You welcome !!!

Comment: You can also use `#pragma warning disable IDE0002 // Simplify Member Access` btw